# Where are GridFS mongodb collection stored on disk?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Are GridFS buckets stored together with the data? 
Do both use `storage.dbPath` from config? 
Is there a way to separate them? 
Am I missing some configuration option?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but there is no specific indication of the location on disc of gridfs in documentation other than "GridFS uses two collections"